# How to display image inside container of custom made widget

Tags: custom-field, widgets

I have a custom made widget, and to a front-end display, I want to display the image that the administrator can add url in custom field. Now I get it displayed outside `.widget` class and so I can't align it properly with flexbox as I did my other two text elements which sit perfectly inside `.widget` container. If I try to concatenate `<img>` before `$args['after_title'];` I get syntax error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'`.

This is the code:

```
<?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title']; ?> <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></img> <?php . $args['after_title']; ?>
  <?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>
    <?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $description . $args['after_title']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `echo` and the `$title`. It should be like this:

```
<?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title']; ?> <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></img> <?php echo $title . $args['after_title']; ?>
```